# Modals created in jinja conditional statement are all showing the same data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am relatively new the web programmer so this may or may not be a solution solvable through JavaScript. If not, please point me in the correct direction.

```
{% for thought in user.thoughts %}

<div class="panel panel-default">

    <!-- Icon to Display Modal -->
    <div class="panel-heading" align="right">
        <a href={{ "/edit/" ~ thought.id }} data-toggle="modal" datatarget="#EditModal" data-placement="left" title="Edit">Icon Here!</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="EditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="LabelModel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content" align="left">

                    <!-- Form in Modal-->
                    <form  action={{ "/editthought/" ~ thought.id }} method="post" role="form">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" type="text">{{ thought.body }}</textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Thought Body -->  
<div class="panel-body">
    {{ thought.body }}
</div>      

{% endfor %}
```

Here I am iterating through every thought associated with a user. Each thought displays a panel showing the thought with an icon to edit the thought.

When you click the icon, a modal pops up with the body of the thought. The issue I'm having is all of the modals contain the same pre-populated thought (the first one in the list).

The link (href={{ "/edit/" ~ thought.id }}) on the edit icon is correct as well as the body of the panel, however when you load the modal, it is not loading the correct thought. Any ideas?

EDIT: I can't figure out how to comment code. Following advice, I took the modal out of the for loop. I'm currently using this function to pass data from my button in the for loop to my modal.

```
<script>function testFun(variable){document.getElementById('thought_id').inne‌​rHTML=variable;}</sc‌​ript>
```

It's working however I can only pass information if it's formatted like this:

```
<h1 id="thought_id"></h1>
```

Is there any way to change this function so I can pass it as a string ike this:

```
<h1>thought_id</h1>
```

Comment: Ah... your modal is in the for loop. I don't see any unique ID to identify the modal. lt will only open the first modal and ignore all the rest in your loop. Technically you could just create a custom id for your modal and links to open them but that isn't too efficient. I would move the modal out of the for loop and then use some JS to update the thought and action path in the modal on click.

Comment: Please see the update, couldn't get the code to work in comments.

Comment: Lets start over here... When you click on the button what items do you need to dynamically update in the modal? Is it only the thought.body in the textarea and the form action? If so I will go ahead and post an additional updated to my answer below.

Comment: Well ideally it would be two arguments. The thought.body in the textarea as well as the thought.id which will be used in the action of the form as action="/editThought/thought.id"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again this is not the most efficient solution but would prevent you from having to pull the modal outside your loop and use JS to update your modal.

**Quick fix for your links datatarget**

```
<a href={{ "/edit/" ~ thought.id }} data-toggle="modal" datatarget="#EditModal_{{thought.id}}" data-placement="left" title="Edit">
```

**Quick Fix to your modal id**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EditModal_{{thought.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="LabelModel">
```

**!!!!! OR GO THE MORE EFFICIENT ROUTE !!!!!**

If you do go the route of moving the dialog out of for loop you can do something like below by adding a class to your links and attache a click event to them. Also add data-thought_id and data-thought_body to the link in your for loop.

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
  $('.thought-link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var action_path = '/editthought/' + $(this).attr('data-thought_id');
    var thought_body = $(this).attr('data-thought_body');
    $('#EditModal form').attr('action', action_path);
    $('#EditModal textarea').text(thought_body);
    $('#EditModal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

**Your new link:**

```
<a href="/edit/{{thought.id}}" data-toggle="modal" datatarget="#EditModal" data-placement="left" title="Edit" class="thought-link" data-thought_body="{{thought.body}}" data-thought_id="{{thought.id}}">Icon Here!</a>
```

**Your modal(outside the for loop):**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="EditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="LabelModel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" align="left">
      <!-- Form in Modal-->
      <form action="" method="post" role="form">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" type="text"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I decided to follow your advice to be more efficient. Now do you know how to pass strings through a js function?

Comment: Hi Anthony, I updated my answer above. Let me know if you encounter other issues.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! And how would you format the code for where I'd be clicking. I'm having trouble figuring out how I'd pass the arguments. This is what I have.

     <a href={{ "/edit/" ~ thought.id }} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditModal" 
     data-thought_id={{ thought.id }} data-thought_body={{ thought.body }}>

Comment: Updated the answer. Keep in mind you may need to do an event stop propagation to kill the href natural behavior. right after the thought-link click. I updated the data attributes in my js to match yours on the link. I also added the proper quotes around the data in your attributes and added the class on there.

Comment: Hi Anthony, I just reformated the code, made a lot of little fixes. Please read the above instuction for !!!!! OR GO THE MORE EFFICIENT ROUTE !!!!!

Comment: Hey Anthony can you mark my answer as best choice so I can get a boost? Thanks!

Comment: Got it! Thanks again.